# how to use window.setTimeout with javascript and the module pattern

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout, module-pattern

i have this example:

```
var myApp = (function() {

    var inputClick = function() {
        console.log('inputClick');
    };

    var loadRecentTimeout = function()
    {
    window.setTimeout("inputClick()",3000);
    };

    return {
      loadRecentTimeout:loadRecentTimeout,
      inputClick:inputClick
    };


})();

myApp.loadRecentTimeout(); // this returns inputClick() undefined

window.setTimeout("myApp.inputClick();",3000); // this one seems to work , but it calls that method only one time and not every 3 seconds
```

can anyone explain how can i make this code call the `inputClick()` method every 3 seconds?

thanks

Comment: you should never pass a string to setInterval or setTimeout.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to call setInterval instead of setTimeout

```
var eventInterval = window.setInterval(function () { 
                        myApp.inputClick(); 
                    },3000);
```

You also should pass your function as a function instead of a string.

If you need to cancel your repeating event you can call `clearInterval`

```
clearInterval(eventInterval)
```

Comment: NEVER pass a string to setInterval.

Comment: there is an unclosed string, what for? the time?

Comment: While I generally agree with @jbabey that is is preferable to pass a function to setInterval/setTimeout, in this case a hard coded string would be safe. What you should NEVER do is pass a string that contains user input to setInterval/setTimeout.

Answer (score 1):

When you use a string "functionName()" it evals it in window scope. Instead, assign a reference to the function with just using the name. setTimeout only fires once, you want to use a setInterval.

```
var myApp = (function() {

    var inputClick = function() {
        console.log('inputClick');
    };

    var loadRecentTimeout = function()
    {
        window.setInterval(inputClick,3000); 
    };

    return {
      loadRecentTimeout:loadRecentTimeout,
      inputClick:inputClick
    };


})();
```